# Can't get broadcastreceive from incoming message

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have a `BroadcastReceiver` declared in the following AndroidManifest.xml, but I never get the SMS_RECEIVED broadcast. Any ideas what is happening?

This is the `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
public class SMSReceiver1 extends BroadcastReceiver 
{ 
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "Thiri The Wut Yee";

    private static final String ACTION = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Receive ");
        Toast.makeText(context, "RECEIVED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

And the AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="android_programmers_guide.SMSReceiver1"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <receiver android:name=".SMSReceiver1"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
            </intent-filter>
       </receiver>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have this permission in your manifest?

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />`

Comment: I don't understand your comment.

Comment: <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>

Comment: That's an action declaration, not a permission declaration. Add the code I have above inside your <manifest /> tags.

Comment: If this answer helped you, would you mind marking it as the answer to your question?

Comment: Again, can I use this.abortBroadcast(); in the code to abort the incoming message alert. I've tried inserted that but everything goes as usual.